# Haskell : Using Tuple in a Persist.Sql - Database as PersistSqlField

Tags: sql, database, haskell, tuples, persist

I have created a database in which I would like to have a Field of the type [(String, [String])].

```
    share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"][persistLowerCase|
    ConfigDB
        numberOfParticipants Int
        groupId              Int
        memberList           [(String,[String])]
        deriving Show
    |]
```

However, I get an error message:

> Exception when trying to run compile-time code: Invalid field type >"[(String,[String])]" PSFail PSFail "PSFail \"(\\"\\",\\"\\",Nothing)\"

The error seems to arise from using a tuple, because [String] works just fine, but if I write (String, String) the compiler tells me:

> "Not in scope: type constructor or class String,
>   Perhaps you meant String (imported from Prelude)"

In Database.Persist.Sql I find 
(PersistFieldSql a, PersistFieldSql b) => PersistFieldSql (a, b) is an instance, so it should work.

Also, importing Data.Tuple didn't help.
I have imported Database.Persist.Sqlite, of course.

Thanks in advance,

Sophia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky (and sometimes impossible) to embed complex types inside the persistent definition syntax. My recommendation is to define a type synonym in your Haskell code, e.g.:

```
type MemberList = [(String, [String])]
```

and then use that type inside the definition.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still puzzled since I trusted the inductive definition of the PersistentFieldSql instances to resolve this and I thought I just had to add the correct imports.